# What is wrong with my database file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

this is my **database.js** file:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const db = function(){
    return MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/users', (err, database) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      return database;
    });
}

module.exports = db;
```

I icluded it to my **server.js** like this:

```
var db = require('./database');
```

but when I want to use it like this

```
db().collection('orders')
```

I am getting a TypeError (Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined)

Edit: sorry, I made an issue during writing this question of course I used `db().collection`

Comment: `var db = require('./database');`

Comment: try db().collection

Comment: sorry, it was correct in the code, so the issue is somewhere else

Comment: `db` is a function which returns the Mongo client object, so you'll need to use `db() `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your export, and misunderstood behavior of node's callbacks.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const db = function(){
    return MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/users', (err, database) => {
      // this is inside a callback, you cannot use the database object outside this scope
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      return database; // this database object is what you should be exporting
    });
}

module.exports = db; // You are exporting the wrong variable
```

One way to fix this is (may not be the best) to export the database object that we receive in the callback. Example:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
let database = null;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/users', (err, db) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      database = db;
});

module.exports = database;
```

And now you can use the db, but with a null check.

```
var db = require('./database');
if (db !== null) {
    db.collection('orders').find({}, (err, docs) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log(docs);
    });
}
```

But this may lead to connection being established again and again when you require the database.js file (I am not sure about this). A better approach would be:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
let database = null;

const connect = () => {
    if (database !== null) return Promise.resolve(database);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/users', (err, db) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            database = db;
            resolve(database);
        });
    });
};

module.exports = connect;
```

and then use it like:

```
var dbConnect = require('./database');
dbConnect().then((db) => {
    db.collection('orders').find({}, (err, docs) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log(docs);
    });
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: `require` gets cached. connecting to a database will be much slower than reaching the export, so it will always be `null`

Comment: @cdbajorin That clears all my doubts with the first approach. Thank you very much!